# How to select most recent record for each with a different foreign key

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that has the following structure.

```
+--+------+---+-------------------+
|id|cardId|elo|timestamp          |
+--+------+---+-------------------+
|1 |000ac9|150|2018-12-19 17:49:16|
|2 |000ac9|160|2018-12-19 17:59:16|
|3 |000ad9|140|2018-12-19 18:21:16|
|4 |000ac9|130|2018-12-19 17:59:16|
|5 |000ad9|260|2018-12-19 19:01:16|
+--+------+---+-------------------+
```

i would like to get the most recent `elo` for each `cardId`.

I have tried to used the Distinctive key word but that doesn't always give me the most recent entry into the database.

I expect something like the following.

```
+--+------+---+-------------------+
|id|cardId|elo|timestamp          |
+--+------+---+-------------------+
|4 |000ac9|130|2018-12-19 17:59:16|
|5 |000ad9|260|2018-12-19 19:01:16|
+--+------+---+-------------------+
```

Comment: You have two values for `cardId=000ac9` with the same timestamp. If that is possible in the real data, do you want both values or just one? If just one, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, available in MySQL 8.x:

```
select * from (
  select
    id,
    cardId,
    elo,
    timestamp,
    row_number() over(partition by cardId order by timestamp desc) as rn
  from my_table
) x
where rn = 1
```